# Best way to flip THREE.Sprite in r84?

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite, scale

I've upgraded my game engine from `r69` to `r84`. Most things were fine but there are few things that are breaking, this is one of them.

Previously I was able to flip sprites by simply doing

```
sprite.scale.x = -1;
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore in `r84`. Not entirely sure why, can anyone provide a recommended way to achieve this now? My current idea will be to store two versions of the texture and simply switch between them, but this seems pretty inefficient and messy compared to the previous solution.

`r84`

Comment: Is setting `sprite.material.map.repeat.set( - 1, 1 );` acceptable? Be sure to set `THREE.RepeatWrapping` as appropriate, also.

Comment: Hmm well I am using a sprite sheet and my code is `texture.repeat.set(1 / spriteSheet.cols, 1 / spriteSheet.rows)`, how could I change this to work with the new method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a sprite sheet and want to flip the image of an individual sprite.

You can do that with `THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping` using a pattern like so:

```
// desired sprite row/column index
var iCol = 5;
var iRow = 3;
var flipSprite = true;

// texture
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( "mySpriteMap.jpg" );

// set wrapping to support flipping sprite
texture.wrapS = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;

// set repeat
var nRows = 8; // sprite sheet: 8 rows x 8 cols
var nCols = 8;
texture.repeat.set( 1 / nCols, 1 / nRows );

// set offset
texture.offset.x = flipSprite ? - ( iCol + 1 ) / nCols : ( iCol / nCols ); // MirroredRepeatWrapping;
texture.offset.y = iRow / nRows;

// material
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture } );

// sprite
sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
```

three.js r.84

Comment: Hmm this is not going to work if you have different frames in your sprite sheet on the x axis right? My animation does `texture.offset.x = frames[frame] / cols` where `texture` is the `material.map`. If you flip based on `texture.offset.x` then that will never work if you are already animating based on horizontal frames. It will always get overidden.

Comment: Okay... I've updated my animation to 

`spritesheet.offset.x = (flip) ? - (framesOrdered[frame] + 1) / cols : framesOrdered[frame] / cols;`

And this works. I don't think it's as clean as the previous implementation though, a lot more work and very fiddly for the same result. Any way to force the old way to work in `r84`?

Comment: three.js does not, and never has, supported reflections in the object matrix. The fact that it used to "work" -- and still may work in certain circumstances -- was simply fortuitous.

Comment: Ok right so this is considered the best practice approach now, cool. I wrote a wrapper method to handle it so it's all good now. Thanks!